# ADT18, App Engine Connected Android project and noclassdeffounderror

Tags: android, google-app-engine, adt

Disclaimer...I *think* I've gone through all of the related posts on this topic and so far, none of them have fixed my problem.  That being said, if I missed something, feel free to point me in the proper direction.

Environment:

-newly configured Eclipse Indigo

-ADT 18

-GWT 2.4

-App Engine SDK 1.6.4

I'm attempting to create a standard, no frills boilerplate "App Engine Connected Android Project" to begin learning how things are handled between App Engine and Android.

After completing the File > New > App Engine Connected Android project (with a functional C2DM role email and password) I get the MyTasks-Android and MyTasks-AppEngine projects in Eclipse.

Knowing the whole lib versus libs issue with ADT17+, I change the lib folder in the MyTasks-Android project to libs and update the build path for the three jars (c2dm.jar, requestfactory-client.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar).  I also add the MyTasks-AppEngine project to the build path.

Once that's all done, I try to run the App-Android project on my device.

I am able to select my Android account, "allow" it to access my account and I see the "say hello" button.  Upon clicking the button, I get the following error in Eclipse:

```
05-01 22:13:22.965: E/dalvikvm(17457): Could not find class 'com.mytasks.client.MyRequestFactory', referenced from method com.mytasks.MyTasksActivity$2$1.doInBackground
05-01 22:13:22.965: W/dalvikvm(17457): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 315 (Lcom/mytasks/client/MyRequestFactory;) in Lcom/mytasks/MyTasksActivity$2$1;
05-01 22:13:22.965: D/dalvikvm(17457): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000a
05-01 22:13:22.973: W/dalvikvm(17457): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a291f8)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mytasks.client.MyRequestFactory
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at com.mytasks.MyTasksActivity$2$1.doInBackground(MyTasksActivity.java:145)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at com.mytasks.MyTasksActivity$2$1.doInBackground(MyTasksActivity.java:1)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-01 22:13:22.989: E/AndroidRuntime(17457):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

I've been working on this all day and so far, no luck.  So, if anyone has any suggestions, I would definitely appreciate the assistance.

Thanks!

EDIT - 5/2/2012 - added setHelloWorldScreenContent from MyTasksActivity class.  Specifically, failing at: *MyRequestFactory requestFactory = Util.getRequestFactory(mContext, MyRequestFactory.class);*

Again, this is a vanilla wizard-generated App Engine Connected Android project - the only change I made was adding the MyTasks-AppEngine to the MyTasks-Android build path and changing lib to libs, then readding the three jars to the build path.

```
private void setHelloWorldScreenContent() {
    setContentView(R.layout.hello_world);

    final TextView helloWorld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
    final Button sayHelloButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.say_hello);
    sayHelloButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sayHelloButton.setEnabled(false);
            helloWorld.setText(R.string.contacting_server);

            // Use an AsyncTask to avoid blocking the UI thread
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                private String message;

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    MyRequestFactory requestFactory = Util.getRequestFactory(mContext, MyRequestFactory.class);
                    final HelloWorldRequest request = requestFactory.helloWorldRequest();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Sending request to server");
                    request.getMessage().fire(new Receiver<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                            message = "Failure: " + error.getMessage();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String result) {
                            message = result;
                        }
                    });
                    return message;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    helloWorld.setText(result);
                    sayHelloButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your MyTasksActivity class (the parts involved in your error).

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. I also just changed the folder name from lib to libs and added back the 3 jars in build path in andorid project and it worked.

Comment: If you've read the question carefully, you would have seen that the OP already did this.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 4 hours on it, the standard lib->libs didnt help me, at the end the solution was compile with jdk 1.6 not 1.7, it means you have to compile even the shared libraries from appengine (well logically) compile with 1.6